# Finding the current user in the session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, session

[image]

Friends help me here;
Looking at the current_user method in the screenshot above, when a user first logs in, the instance variable @current_user will be assigned the User object. But when makes subsequent requests, the presence of user_id in the session is tested and if found, the @current_user is returned if previously assigned, otherwise assigned and returned. My question here is: if the previous assignment of the @current_user is used to determine a logged-in state, how do we know that the user from the new request is the same as the one previously assigned to @current_user?.
Your contributions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Because the session represents the specific users's session, whether or not they are logged in.  Read up on sessions here...https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/

Comment: Please post code as formatted code text, not as an image, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a fundamental logic error here.

Controller instance variables only exist in the scope of a single request. When a request hits your rails application it matches the request to your routes. The routes give a controller / action combination and Rails uses this information to instantiate a new instance of the controller class and call the correct method on it.

This code does not actually in any way persist anything *across requests*:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

Rather it uses conditional assignment to prevent running `User.find_by` repeatedly (and thus querying the database) in *the same request*.

This is a technique known as memoization.

The [session](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) on the other hand persists between requests since it  is stored in a cookie that is passed back and forth between the client and server.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying thing here.